# SQL Server 2008: Is it possible to store differential backups in a separate files?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2008, migration, backup-restoration

We're moving some of our applications to a new hosting provider and we want to make it seamless for our users. Nonetheless, we have big databases and we've got to move about 48GB of data.

Our proposal -if it's possible- is taking full backups of our databases and move them to our new servers. once the backups upload is finished, we're going to take differential backups from our databases and move them to the new server to finish the data migration.

Then, is it possible to create a differential backup in a separate file from the full backup?

EDIT:

I used [this procedure](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/ssms-how-to-restore-differential-backups/) to do it using SSMS

> In order to restore a differential
>   backup, you will first need to restore
>   the last full backup with NO RECOVERY
>   option. So, in SSMS you need to select
>   the appropriate full-backup and choose
>   Restore With NoRecovery option from
>   the Options page. Once restored, the
>   database will be shown in the Object
>   Explorer as Restoring. Notice that the
>   database is
>   non-available/non-functional at this
>   time and is waiting for a differential
>   backup to be applied. Now, restore the
>   appropriate differential backup and
>   choose Restore With Recovery from the
>   Options page. That’s it. You have
>   successfully restored a differential
>   backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have separate files for differentials.